# ACTION SCRIPT 3 - cant stop a function

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a small little game made where objects fall and a score goes up, if you hit the object with your mouse you lose and go to the loser page and if the score reaches 500 you win and go to the winners page.

It works however when at the losers page for example it seems like the score is still running in the background and when it reaches 500 it goes to the next frame despite having stop();

Here is my code for the game frame:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var score = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop (e:Event) {

if(score >= 100) {
    score = 0;
    gotoAndStop(8);

}


score ++;
score_text.text = score;

var r1:int = Math.random() * 700;
var r2:int = Math.random() * 700;
var r3:int = Math.random() * 700;
var r4:int = Math.random() * 700;


clapper1.rotation += 10;
clapper2.rotation += 10;
clapper3.rotation += 10;
clapper4.rotation += 10;
if (clapper1.y >= 470.2) {
    clapper1.x = r1;
    clapper1.y = -76.5;
}
if (clapper2.y >= 470.2) {
    clapper2.x = r2;
    clapper2.y = -76.5;
}
if (clapper3.y >= 470.2) {
    clapper3.x = r3;
    clapper3.y = -76.5;
}
if (clapper4.y >= 470.2) {
    clapper4.x = r4;
    clapper4.y = -76.5;
}


clapper1.y += 15;
clapper2.y += 8;
clapper3.y += 10;
clapper4.y += 20;
}

clapper1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor1);
function mor1(e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop(7);

}
clapper2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor2);
function mor2(e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop(7);

}
clapper3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor3);
function mor3(e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop(7);

}
clapper4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor4);
function mor4(e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop(7);

}
```

Comment: Your code is missing

Comment: Sorry i just copy and pasted the code didnt realize it went through wrong, should be up now

Comment: Is the 100 in your `if(score >= 100)` the same thing as the 500 in your description? Is frame 8 the winners page? Since you added to stage an `ENTER_FRAME` loop thats adds up the score, why not remove it from stage before telling app to go to frame 8? See **[this guide](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/)** for a hint.

Comment: Hi, yes the 100 is the 500 I set it has 100 to see if it was the case of the score still going. Frame 8 is the winners page yes, thought I had changed that to frame caption rather than number. Will take a look at the guide thank you

Comment: Working now! thank you so much!